# mongo.Connect() not working as expected in Go using the mongo-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, go

I am using the package: `"github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo"`

I am trying to use the following as specified in the [documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo):

```
mongoContext, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
mongoClient, _ := mongo.Connect(mongoContext, "mongodb://localhost:27017")
```

However on the second line I get the error:

```
cannot use "mongodb://localhost:27017" (type string) as type *options.ClientOptions in argument to mongo.Connect
```

It seems the documentation doesn't match the implementation. Has anyone been successful?

**The documentation states:**

```
//To do this in a single step, you can use the Connect function:
ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, "mongodb://localhost:27017")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation states that the `Connect` method have to use a context object.
It also provides an example of usage:

You connection string have to be provided to the `NewClient` function first.

```golang
client, err := mongo.NewClient(mongo.options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
if err != nil {
    // error
}
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()
err = client.Connect(ctx)
if err != nil {
    // error
}

// here you can use the client object
```

https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo#Client.Connect

To use it as a single step as you try to do, you should be able to do:

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()
mongoClient, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, mongo.options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
if err != nil {
    // error
}
```

(The connection string has to be put inside an options.ClientOptions object, and the `options.Client().ApplyURI()` method will take care of it)

Comment: Indeed, I updated my answer to include what I guess it should be

Comment: Thank you, that solves my problem. They probably need to update their documentation to make it consistent.

Comment: Agreed, that is also why I didn't understand what you tried to do on the first look. Doc is unclear